# EF LINQ Query - Many to Many

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I need some help getting some data from an EF 4.1 query.

I have a `Products` table and a `Categories` table that have a Many-To-Many relationship on them.

I need to select a product by ID and include in it the categories it is associated with.

I came up with this:

```
    Public Function GetProductByID(ID As Integer) As Core.Entities.Product Implements Core.Interfaces.IProductService.GetProductByID
        Dim p = ProductRepository.Query.Single(Function(x) x.ID = ID)
        p.Categories = CategoryRepository.Query.Where(Function(x) x.Products.Any(Function(y) y.ID = ID)).ToList

        Return p

    End Function
```

I am sure there is a better way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use `Include()` provided you have a property `Categories` on your `Product` entity? (C# syntax):

```
var p = ProductRepository.Include(x=> x.Categories)
                         .Single(x => x.ID == ID);
```

Also see [Loading Related Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896272.aspx)